# EFI partition is showing all 260mb are used, even though it's only got 34mb used, even after restart?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, uefi, gparted

This persists after a reboot, as well.

I'm using Pop OS. I tried to move the partition, confident I could just follow [their instructions](https://support.system76.com/articles/bootloader/) to repair the boot.

The instructions (slightly modified for my system):

```bsh
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mnt  
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi

for i in dev dev/pts proc sys run; do sudo mount -B /$i /mnt/$i; done
sudo cp -n /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/
sudo chroot /mnt
apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
update-initramfs -c -k all
exit
sudo bootctl --path=/mnt/boot/efi install
```

problem is, this command: `update-initramfs -c -k all` fails, because it thinks there is no space.

```bsh
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/proc/cmdline' -> '/boot/efi/EFI/Pop_OS-0bb250ea-43ea-4e62-8e06-4380542bdcfd/cmdline'
```

(full output can be seen [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/r97gcv/comment/hnad8mo/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).)

There's definitely space though. Looking in Nautilus, it's actually 34mb.

[image]

Of note: I dual boot windows.

Here's my drive right now... you can see gparted (same as df -h) thinks it's completely full:

[image: gparted]

What is going on? A reboot doesn't change this, btw.

Answer (score 0):

well, that was silly: it was just a hidden folder called .TRASH. Deleting files did not send them into the visible $RECYCLEBIN, but to a hidden .TRASH, even though nautilus gave me an error message telling me that the files wouldn't go to trash but would be completely deleted... Nice.

Unfortunately, this happens every time I follow their instructions. My EFI partition is just not big enough to run `update-initramfs`... had to resize, which meant moving my windows partition, which means I'll have to probably destroy that and make a new one from scratch. :/

Comment: 260 Mb is a PLENTY of the room for the ESP. Mine has 127M and It is still too many, because around 23M of it is used, or at most 60M when in the middle of the upadte.

Comment: That sounds like it makes sense in theory, but update-initramfs won't work in that small of a context, and is probably why pop-os says it should be 512mb. update-initramfs loading the generic kernels is around 100-150mb range, and it tries to make a backup. It just hits a limit and runs out of space. I was unable to find a workaround for this, though I'm sure it's possible by making a custom kernel, or by running update-initramfs in a different location and then copy/pasting result, but wasn't able to solve within my time crunch. :(

Comment: just checked, btw. The output that it wants to create in its EFI folder is 237mb... combined with the 32mb I have existing in there, that means just enough that the 260mb wasn't enough. If I had known it would be that close, I would have considered deleting some other files/folders--or perhaps just backed them up, run this command, removed the initrd.img-previous and vmlinuz-previou.efi, and then restored them, saving my windows partition. I had no way to really know how much space short I was, seems I was just barely below the limit.